# Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to double[]

Tags: java, arrays, constructor, double

```
public class DSAStack
{
    private int count;
    private double[] stack;
    public static final int default_capacity = 100;

    public DSAStack()
    { 
        this.stack = stack[default_capacity];
        this.count = 0;
    }

    public DSAStack(int capacity)
    { 
        this.stack = stack[capacity];
        this.count = 0;
    }
}
```

Eclipse recommended quick fix to make no change, simply highlights `double[]`, probably a really stupid error but I can't figure it out.

Comment: `new stack[default_capacity]`

Comment: I suggest you change the first constructor code to `this(default_capacity);` to use the `DSAStack(int)`, this will be less redondant. For the rest, see the answer to understand the problem.

Comment: stack[capacity] returns an element after the last element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean

```
this.stack = new double[default_capacity];
```

and also

```
this.stack = new double[capacity];
```

Comment: Yep, I feel stupid figured it out as soon as I posted it. Thx

Comment: No problem, sometimes it just happens.

Comment: Please delete the question to avoid contribuing toward question ban

Comment: I went to delete it as soon as I found the answer, but you guys were too quick and answered it before I could, now I can't.

Answer (score 0):

In `this.stack = stack[default_capacity];` you try to insert value to `stack` in the index equals to `default_capacity`, which is `double`. Therefor the error

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to double[]

You need to initialize `stack` using `new`

```
this.stack = new double[default_capacity];
```

Answer (score 0):

this.stack = stack[default_capacity]

stack is double [].
stack [default_capacity] is double.

Comment: You should try to use the code tag to format your answer. If english is not easy for you, at least the code will be readable ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should write it with new:

```
this.stack = new stack[default_capacity];
```

Answer (score -1):

Double is a class type. nextDouble returns the primitive type double. Change A to double array

double[] A = new double[Size];

Comment: This doesn't make sense, OP use a primitive type array `double[]` not `Double[]`. So this is not an array of class at all. What is this `nextDouble` that return a primitive type ? This is unclear.